# Woocommerce - Change Product Gallery Image Selecting Only Variation

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce

I would like to change product gallery image when a single colour variation is selected, rather than having to fill out all the other options first.

Setting defaults, plugins, custom code - i just cannot get this to work.

Comment: Please provide code and edit the question to reflect what is being attempted with the code and where the issue(s) occur.

Comment: @Trenton_M where should I post my question because I need helping starting with the code from scratch. I can probably sort out the code but I’ve no idea where to start or how to approach it. Is there a preferred board for that?

Comment: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)